# Android Studio throws "'Runtime' is not a supported scope" when importing project

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem importing a `gradle project` and maybe some of you can help me with this:

When I import an android project I get the following error message and the import gets cancelled:

```
Gradle 'myProject' project refreshed failed: //'Runtime' is not a supported scope. Supported scopes are [Compile, Test].: Gradle settings (a minute ago)
```

The project can be build on another machine but importing it on another doesn't work.

EDIT and SOLUTION: A non Android project which was part of 'myProject' had a dependency with runtime instead of compile. I don't know if the non Android project will run with compile but at least you should be able to import the project as a whole. If needed you can revert the changes and just receive a warning when starting Android Studio.